# Which Banach spaces admit medians?

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

In a metric space $X$, let $I(x,y)$ denote the metric interval between two points, i.e. $I(x,y):=\{z:d(z,x)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)\}$. Given a triplet $(x,y,z)$, we say that $w$ is a median of the triplet if $w\in I(x,y)\cap I(x,z)\cap I(y,z)$. By some metric geometry, it is known that every 1-injective Banach space admits medians (see below). Is this a complete characterization? If not, what's an example of such a Banach space?

Addendum: Proof of "every 1-injective space admits medians".

It is well known that a Banach space is 1-injective iff it is an [injective metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_metric_space) (also known as tight or hyperconvex metric space). Thus the result follows if we prove that every injective metric space admits medians. To do that, let $x,y,z\in X$ ($X$ injective metric space). If one of $(x|y)_z, (x|z)_y, (y|z)_x$ is zero (here $(x|y)_z$ denotes the [Gromov product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_product)), then the base point is already the median. If not, we construct a metric space $\{x,y,z,a\}$ with $d(a,x)=(y|z)_x$ and similarly for the other points and then use injectivity to get a Lipschitz embedding of $\{x,y,z,a\}$ in $X$. The image of $a$ in $X$ is the desidered median.

2° Addendum: to give some idea of the problem, here's an example of a Banach space with medians and a sketch of how to find them: $\ell^\infty_2$. In it, the metric segment between two points $x,y$ consists of the (possibly degenerate) rectangle with two sides parallel to the diagonal having $x$ and $y$ as vertices. This means that the set of medians of three points is simply the intersection of the rectangles.

Comment: The wikipedia definition of geometric median seem to easily generalize to any Banach space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median Now, as far as I understand it, your definition of median is different, but what is not clear to me is how you can make sure that the intersection of the 3 line segment is not empty. Seems to me that already in $\Bbb R^2$ with the euclidean distance and $x,y,z$ forming a non-degenerated triangle, such $w$ would not exist.

Comment: @Surb: The definition of median I use is the one from metric geometry, admittedy different from the more classical one. While it is true that $\ell_2^2$ does not admit metric medians in general, it is not difficult to find examples  of Banach spaces admitting metric medians: as some finite dimensional examples consider $\ell_2^1, \ell_n^\infty$. Ensuring the nonemptyness of the intersection is exactly the issue here (althought for general Banach spaces the metric interval is not necessarily a line segment)

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification and further examples. So, if I get it correctly, smooth Banach spaces are basically out.

Comment: Could you please share further details on your progress on the question? E.g. by illustrating one or two examples of medians and sketching the steps towards the proof of "it is known that every 1-injective Banach space admits medians". I am really interested by the question and would like to add a bounty but feel that the question could first benefit some improvement.

Comment: For instance giving examples of metric segments would already be useful, as far as I understood: the metric segment in $\ell^\infty_2$ between $x$ and $y$ consists of the points in the rectangle having $x$ and $y$ as opposed vertexes, while the metric segment in $\ell^{\infty}$ consists of the boundary of the latter rectangle.

Comment: @Surb I've added some more detail, let me know if you have any more questions. The $\ell_\infty$ example is basically the only example of nontrivial metric segment one can make in finite dimensions for injective spaces, since every f.d. 1-inj. Banach space is isometric to $\ell^\infty_n$ for some $n$. The only other exampl of nontrivial metric segments one can make for f.d. vector spaces is $\ell^1_n$, but in two dimensions that's just a rotation of $\ell^\infty$ and in more it gets pretty hard to draw.